# Keycloak, create clients with custom role using the UI

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

this is my very first question here so apologies in advance for any breach of etiquette.

My company swapping auth0 for keycloak and i'm doing some exploratory work to support that. Im no Identity expert so apologies for any misconceptions and gaffes.
In auth0, we have a backend-service that authenticates with the admin api and manages users that way. i'm trying to replicate that scenario using keycloak and havent been successful. Part of it is that there is lots of moving parts and literature on keycloak and im assimilating all that.

I can solve my requirement if i create a client (on master realm) and assign it the admin realm-role. What i actually want is to be more restrictive, i.e: create a separate realm, create the client in that realm and then assign it only the equivalent of master-realm's manage-users role.

I have been trying for 2 days but haven't been successful.
One small note, i have seen alot of resources referencing urls like http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/claim-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token
and that gives 404 for me, but i can get to work if i remove the /auth.
I'm running quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:22.0.1 so maybe im missing some setting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use old token URL. There are no `/auth` in new Keycloak version since V20.
So you can use new URL. `http://localhost:8080/realms/claim-dev/protocol/openid-connect/token`

Comment: i have it working, just didn't know that was considered "old" urls, thanks